# writing to sdcard

Tags: android

i have a very small problem. I am writing a file to sdcard. I'l show you two code, one code works and other doesn't. It looks like this:
First one,

```
new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/HelloWorld.txt")
```

This works fine and creates a HelloWorld.txt file in sdcard.

Now second one,

```
  new FileOutputStream(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+java.io.File.separator + "filetest" + java.io.File.separator + "HelloWorld.txt")
```

This throws error "`/mnt/sdcard/filetest/HelloWorld.txt (No such file or directory)`".
I want to know why because i have mnt/sdcard path on my device, is it that it cannot find filetest folder if yes then isn't it supposed to create filetest folder if its not created before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Make a directory of `filetest` if its not available,

```
File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+java.io.File.separator + "filetest");

file.mkdir();
```

Then execute your code...

OR

```
File f =    new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+java.io.File.separator + "filetest" + java.io.File.separator + "HelloWorld.txt");

    if (!f.getParentFile().exists());
    {
        f.getParentFile().mkdir();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes........** filetest folder are not there so you need to create it manually or programatically.and try that code...so you get success.

**you can also create dir like this ::**

```
File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/filetest/");
// have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
// create a File object for the output file
File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, filename);
// now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

**Use Permission :::**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```